# Routing & Navigation: Cannot access any other routes on web page

Tags: angular, routes, navigation, components, angular8

I am using Angular 8 and am having trouble with routes on my page. I have generated the components I need as well as declaring them and importing them with their necessary paths in order to navigate on the web page.

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router";

import { AngularFireModule } from "@angular/fire";
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from "@angular/fire/auth";
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from "@angular/fire/firestore";

import { HomeComponent } from "./home/home.component";
import { LoginComponent } from "./login/login.component";
import { SignupComponent } from "./signup/signup.component";

import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { environment } from "src/environments/environment";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, HomeComponent, LoginComponent, SignupComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: "", component: HomeComponent },
      { path: "login", component: LoginComponent },
      { path: "signup", component: SignupComponent }
    ]),
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFirestoreModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

app-routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { HomeComponent } from "./home/home.component";
import { LoginComponent } from "./login/login.component";
import { SignupComponent } from "./signup/signup.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "login",
    component: LoginComponent
  },

  {
    path: "home",
    component: HomeComponent
  },

  {
    path: "signup",
    component: SignupComponent
  },
  {
    path: "",
    redirectTo: "/home",
    pathMatch: "full"
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Since I have added all the necessary components to the app module, shouldn't it just work when i change URL and add /login or /signup?
Also a side note, I am unable to see my html code in the components. The only place where it is visible and can be seen on my site is the index.html. Is this related to my components?

Comment: Do you have `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` tags anywhere in your HTML template?

Comment: Yes, in my app.component.html.

Comment: Why do you have both `RouterModule.forRoot([` in AppModule but then also import a routing module that also does `RouterModule.forRoot([`? It also doesn't help as they have some of the same routes in both.

Comment: Looks like I was testing both scenarios to see if one would work over the other. Is one better than the other?

Comment: It's better using the `AppRoutingModule`. Delete that `RouterModule.forRoot(...)` in your appModule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are declaring the empty route before the other routes. Angular will always send you to the first url it matches. In your case, the `{ path: "", component: HomeComponent }` is the first match regardless the url you are trying to access.

A tip: try using always a RoutingModule like you are, but without a the import `RouterModule.forRoot(...)`. Just by removing that it should work.

Comment: Thanks Jorge, I was able to remove the Routing-module in my app-module although I am still having trouble routing to my different components. One thing I noticed is that when I change the URL to /login for instance, for a split second I see a blank white screen (login component) and then a gray screen which is my home page. Do I need router outlets in my component as well? Also i'm unable to see my html code in the components. Only place where it is visible and can be seen on my site is the index.html and only then is when I see the login component with html code again for a split second.

Comment: You will always trigger the `""` route. If you go to /login, you will get the login component with the component from empty route together. If you want to redirect at any route, you should use `path: "**"`

Comment: Okay makes sense. Still not having any luck with routing... Not sure what the problem is I did everything you suggested

Comment: If you want, make a StackBlitz so I can help you

Comment: Ok, I just decided to start fresh and create a new project, now my routing works. Thanks for the help